# Python Matplotlib scatterplot plots axis with inconsistent numbers

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am plotting a dataset of months vs temperatures (y-axis) and I use:

```
plt.scatter(time, temps)
plt.show()
```

but in the plot the y-axis is not consistent (point 8 has a value of 19.5749 but its shown higher than the previous point at 22.482)
[image: matplotlib graph]

Comment: Try to use a simple `plt.plot(time, temps)`

Comment: This can only happen if your `temps` series is a series of strings.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right it is a series of strings. Thank you sooooo much I have been looking at the wrong thing..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have read in your `temps` series as a series of strings, which means that its exact values are written on the y-axis. If you convert it to `float` with the `astype` function, it works properly.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([ 0, 1, 2, 3 ])
y = np.array(['3.1', '2.2', '7.3', '4.5'])

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.title('string')

y = y.astype(np.float)

plt.subplot(122)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.title('float')
plt.show()
```

The script above results in the following picture.

[image]